# Good textbook for a first-course in Complex Analysis for independent study

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, reference-request, self-learning

I am nearly done going through Abbott's *Understanding Analysis* textbook (covering all topics), and will be looking to move onto Complex Analysis next. I am looking for a similarly engaging textbook, geared toward a self-learner, or at least one that is at the right level and has accessible solutions to the exercises.

I will be pairing it with Tristan Needham's *Visual Complex Analysis* book to try and build an intuitive understanding of the subject matter, which I have heard brilliant things about, but I also heard that it is not rigourous enough to use as a stand-alone text for a full first course on the subject. At the moment, I have Stein & Shakarchi's *Complex Analysis* textbook on my shortlist, but looking to get some more recommendations if you think there is something more appropriate for my level!

Also, if you know of any other good types of resources (online courses, video lectures, etc) on the subject I would be really interested to hear about those too! Thanks.

Comment: I am happy with "An Introduction to Complex Function Theory" (Palka).